# chai nodejs and mongodb

Tags: node.js, mongodb, chai

Iḿ trying to validade an object with Chai and Mongodb inside my nodejs testing. But I could not chain objects in there. Here's my model :

```
const PatientSchema = new mongoose.Schema(
 {
  userId: { type: mongoose.Schema.Types.ObjectId, ref: "user" },
  name: {
    type: String,
    required: true,
  },
  cpf: {
    type: String,
    required: true,
    validate: {
      validator: (v) => {
      return /^\d{3}\d{3}\d{3}\d{2}$/.test(v);
    },
    message: (props) => {
      `${v} is not a valid CPF number formated!`;
    },
  },
  },
  identity: {
    type: String,
    unique: "Exists",
  },
  telephone: {
    type: String,
  },
  password: {
    type: String,
  },
  sex: {
    type: String,
  },
  dateOfBirth: {
    type: Date,
  },
  membership: {
    mothersName: {
      type: String,
    },
    fathersName: {
      type: String,
    },
  },...


My chai object I'm testing as described here :
describe("GET /api/patients", () => {
   it("Should get all the patients", (done) => {
     chai
     .request(server)
     .get("/api/patient")
     .set("Authorization", "someauth")
    .end((err, response) => {
      response.should.have.status(200);
      response.body.should.be.a("Array");
      response.body[0].should.have.property("userId");
      response.body[0].should.have
        .property("membership")
        .to.be.an("object")
        .that.include.all.keys("mothersName", "fathersName");
    }); fails !
```

I want to check inside "membership" the properties of the object ("mothersName",        "fathersName" ...). What I want to do is to check nested object inside a existing one

Comment: If I just put ...       response.body[0].should.have
        .property("membership")
        .to.be.an("object")
        .that.include.all.keys("mothersName"); it works